# Don't reset applet on ajax

Tags: java, jsf, applet

We have JSF 2.0 (primefaces) application with applet included in web page. Something like this.

```
<h:panelGroup id="appletbox" layout="block">
<applet id="termApplet" code=com.foo.TermApplet archive=...>
         <param name=... value=... />
</applet>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The applet is SSH terminal emulation and opens a connection. We call it 
in com.foo.TermApplet - there is a public void method openFrameFromWebPage(String host) which
is called from javascript:

```
function openTerminal(host) {
   var termApplet = document.getElementById("termApplet");
   termApplet.openFrameFromWebPage(host);
```

}

This works just fine. The problem is, everytime the web page this applet is included to makes request (including ajax) - it causes the applet to reset and start from scratch.

Would I would like to do, is somehow exclude the applet from postback. Imagine that you are editing some file in vim in the terminal and click a radio button on web page to different data about the work you must do on the server - and it reset the connection and you loose all unsaved data.

Is there a way how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

popup another browser with do not close warning and open the applet inside it. If the browser is not refreshing and you are doing only ajax, add an iframe and open the applet from it.